# Не подсвечивается JS код на VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Не подсвечиваются некоторые части кода как в Sublime. Например `console.log();`
Как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы устанавливали какие-то расширения? Там Visual Studio Code сама предлагает установить что надо... Для начала тот же ESLint extension поставьте

Comment: Для Js только следующие: JavaScript (ES6) code snippets и jshint.

Comment: Насколько помню, там с Sublime вообще можно экспортировать настройки, там тоже для этого есть расширения какие-то. Наберите в поисковом окне расширений

Comment: Уже делал. Не помогло

Comment: Вот не знаю, у меня только ESLint сейчас стоит, и тот же `console.log();` красиво подсвечивается (проверил в двух разных ОС). Но правда стоит еще [тема от Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Theme-MaterialKit) может влияет как-то...Мне кажется у вас вопрос в элементарной кастомизации

Comment: User Settings>TypeScript> и смотрите все галочки по JScript

Comment: Ребят, сорре, туплю. Это из-за темы Dark (Visual Studio). Поменял, теперь норм))